# Square wave above line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add a square wave above a circuit line. How could I do this in a efficiently way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\draw (0,0) |- (1.5,1) -| (3,0)`

Comment: Ok, that's a more inefficient way for me. Would it be possible to have  add a square wave in terms of a node so you can easily use \draw (0,0) -- node[midway,above=0.3mm]{square wave figure} ++(2,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use for the `pic` syntax:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  square wave/.pic={\draw[scale=.1] (-#1,-.5)
                      \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{-| ++(1,1) -| ++(1,-1)};},
  pics/square wave/.default=2,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- pic[sloped, above=3mm] {square wave} (1,1);
  \draw (0,0) to [bend right] 
     pic[sloped, scale=.5, pos=.7, blue, below=3mm] {square wave=3} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: square wave pic]